# Can I use the ampersand in SASS to reference specific tags with the parent class?

Tags: sass

I have a class `semantic` which I apply to many different elements. Depending on which html tag the class is applied to, I would like it to apply a different style. This is how I tried to do it:

```
.semantic {
    &ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    &p {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. Of course I could write it like this, but it wouldn't be very "DRY":

```
 .semantic ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
 }

 .semantic p {
     margin: 0;
 }
```

Is this possible?

Edit: For clarification, here is an example of what my HTML looks like:

```
<ul class='semantic'>
    <li>An Item</li>
</ul>

<p class='semantic'>This text is semantically a paragraph, but should not be displayed as such</p>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you're wanting for would in theory look like this:

```
.semantic {
    ul& {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    p& {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

This is not possible because the `&` must be first.  You're just going to have to deal with the fact that it isn't DRY and write it out by hand:

```
ul.semantic {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

p.semantic {
    margin: 0;
}
```

As of Sass 3.3 or 3.4, it is possible using this syntax:

```
.semantic {
    ul#{&} {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    p#{&} {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not necessary that `&` be first. The only strict requirement is that `&` must be surrounded by spaces or those special css selector characters `~`, `>`, etc.

Comment: This does not work for me. In Sass 3.4.16 your wxample generates
`.semantic ul.semantic {padding: 0; margin: 0;} .semantic p.semantic {margin: 0;}`

Comment: This doesn't work in Sass 3.4.21.
Instead the solution of @jruz works well.

Comment: Thanks man. It helped me a lot and works well :)

Comment: Clever. Never knew you could do this, but very handy.

Answer (score 74):

On Sass 3.4:

```
.semantic {
    @at-root {
      ul#{&} {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      p#{&} {
        margin: 0;
      }
    }
}
```

Generates:

```
ul.semantic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p.semantic {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[@at-root](http://sassbreak.com/getting-back-to-our-roots/) moves the block to the top-level.  This has several uses (see link) but here it's being used to keep take advantage of the `&` syntax without implying that the rules are child selectors of `.semantic`.

Comment: Can you explain how/why this works?

Comment: Is this possible with two classes? eg: `.semantic, .semantic2 {}`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: **Correlated info:** unfortunatelly it will not works with nested style, because it will apply directly to root element (which make sense once you are using  `@at-root` special selector), not to the parent (https://jsfiddle.net/4g5fL5sp/1/).

Comment: for the record, `@at-root ul#{&}` (on one line) works to

Comment: These kind of false limitations implied on SASS motivate me to write my own css compiler one day when I have time

Answer (score 0):

Because of how CSS specificity works you could just do this:

```
.semantic {
  margin: 0; 
}

ul.semantic {
  padding: 0;
}
```

In your HTML, `p.semantic` and `ul.semantic` would have `margin: 0;` and only `ul.semantic` would have `padding: 0;`

Less Sass, less CSS. DRY.

If, unlike your example, elements on the real site have even less in common, you might want to  rethink why they need to have the same class name.

Comment: The part I was trying to avoid was having to specify `.semantic` for each one. One of the great advantages of SASS is it's nesting. I was trying to avoid having the class name specified more than once (to keep it DRY).