# Multiple tags in 1 sass block

Tags: css, sass

I have a class named `button_class`. Now a button or an input tag could have this class. Now using sass, I need to add something to the css if the tag name is input. Like this:

```
.button_class {
    display: inline-block;

    /* something like this */
    & input {
        padding: 2px;
    }
}
```

As you guessed, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Also see, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268051/sass-combining-parent-using-ampersand-with-base-element, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150621/access-the-parent-selector-from-within-a-sass-mixin, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724861/using-the-ampersand-sass-parent-selector-inside-nested-selectors

Comment: Impossible, unfortunately http://stackoverflow.com/q/15796380/822138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SASS syntax doesn't permit this yet. :(

`&input` gives

> "input" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector