# Ampersand referencing specific tags does not compile on SassMeister

Tags: html, css, sass

According to this topic:

[Can I use the ampersand in SASS to reference specific tags with the parent class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796380/can-i-use-the-ampersand-in-sass-to-reference-specific-tags-with-the-parent-class)

following code

**[try 1]**

```
.specific-style {
  color: red;
  b& {
    color: green;
  }
  span& {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

should return

```
.specific-style {
  color: red;
}
b.specific-style {
  color: green;
}
span.specific-style {
  color: blue;
}
```

but it gives

```
"&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
```

**[try 2]**

```
.specific-style {
  color: red;
  b#{&} {
    color: green;
  }
  span#{&} {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

returns

```
.specific-style {
  color: red;
}
.specific-style b.specific-style {
  color: green;
}
.specific-style span.specific-style {
  color: blue;
}
```

**[try 3]**

```
.parent {
  .specific-style {
    color: red;

    @at-root b#{&}{
      color: green;
    }
    @at-root span#{&} {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```
.parent .specific-style {
  color: red;
}
b.parent .specific-style {
  color: green;
}
span.parent .specific-style {
  color: blue;
}
```

This one is closest so far, but i forgot to mention this should work for **nested selectors** too, as follows:

```
.parent .specific-style {
  color: red;
}
.parent b.specific-style {
  color: green;
}
.parent span.specific-style {
  color: blue;
}
```

Is there a mistake in my code or is it a Sass compiler bug?

Comment: I think you've read it wrong. I am not a Sass user but `@at-root b#{&}` seems to be what you need based on cimmanon's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501114/ampersand-at-the-end-and-part-of-a-selector-in-sass) in the original-original.

Comment: @Harry, Paulie_D Thanks for the comments, I have updated my question with suggested solutions, but still didn't achieve what I need, I forgot to mention this should work for nested selectors too.

Answer (score 2):

After some experimentation, you just repeat the process mentioned in the [**original answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501114/ampersand-at-the-end-and-part-of-a-selector-in-sass)

```
  .specific-style {
    color: red;

    @at-root b#{&}{

         @at-root .parent #{&}{
          color: green;
        }
    }


    @at-root span#{&} {
         @at-root .parent #{&}{
          color: blue;
        }

    }
  }
```

spits out

```
.specific-style {
  color: red;
}
.parent b.specific-style {
  color: green;
}
.parent span.specific-style {
  color: blue;
}
```

[**Sassmeister Demo**](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d694a3bc40829690ae4c)

But that seems a complex way of doing things.

Comment: Haha, yeah repeating the parent selector Inside of the child seems to solve it, but it works only if i know what is the parent selector and paste it two times. I couldn't create an universal mixin by using this solution, but for this exact case, this would solve it, so here is the point.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to avoid using "placeholder-selector", but that is a way i solved this:

```
%colors {
  color: red;
}
b%colors {
  color: green;
}
span%colors {
  color: blue;
}

@mixin colors{
  @extend %colors;
};

.parent {
  .specific-style {
    @include colors;
  }
}
```

**returns**

```
.parent .specific-style {
  color: red;
}

.parent b.specific-style {
  color: green;
}

.parent span.specific-style {
  color: blue;
}
```

\o/